# What is the best method to convert analog to digital as well as level shift the signal?

Tags: sensor

Hypothetical Scenario:  I want to connect a 5v analog sensor to the Pi.  Of course, the Pi's signal processing operates at 3.3v digital.  Please assume that both analog-to-digital conversion and 5v-to-3.3v conversion MUST occur for the sensor to interoperate with the Pi.

First-Impression Solution:  I can connect the sensor to an ADC converter to convert the analog signal to digital.  Then I can connect the ADC to a logic level converter to step-down the signal from 5v to 3.3v.  (My understanding is that level converters require digital signals on both sides).  Finally, I can connect the level converter to the Pi.

Will this work?  Is there a more efficient solution?  I read somewhere that an Op Amp might replace both the ADC and level converter.

Answer (score 2):

I just connect the maximum 5V analogue signal to a 5V capable SPI ADC such as a MCP3xxx and use a pair of resistors as a voltage divider on the ADC digital out line (connected to Pi MISO).

Comment: while I am familiar with the classic voltage divider using a pair of resistors, I always thought of this solution in the context of operating power for the devices, not for signal processing.  Now that you've mentioned it, I'm not sure why I had this narrow view to begin with.  Are there any other considerations involving SPI, or the very low power used for signaling, that need to be factored in when using resistors in this fashion?

Comment: I found answers and related info here: http://forum.arduino.cc/index.php?topic=63789.0

Comment: Further research suggests the resistor pair should be of low resistance values to allow the small current (2ma - 16ma) on the GPIO data channel to pass.  For example, if you are sizing to 8ma, then optimal resistor values would be 221 ohms (upper) and 432 ohms (lower).

Comment: Personally I would use high resistor values when possible.  It minimises the current flow if a higher than expected voltage is fed into the ADC  (e.g. mistakenly being powered from 7V rather than 5V).  If possible keep the maximum current to of the order of 0.1 milliamps.  But, I must repeat, I am a software guy, so take what I say with a pinch of salt.

Comment: Your point is well taken as a good defensive measure.  Would you happen to know the minimum current required for a reliable input signal on the GPIO data channel?  Apparently, we are talking µA.

Comment: I'd definitely be guessing if I mentioned a figure.  From memory I have used 10k and 20k resistors to form a voltage divider.  It will depend on the length of your wires and how noisy your environment is.

Comment: Just realized that my previous comment about sizing the resistor pair for GPIO signal input from a sensor was dead wrong on several points. First, the current range I referenced (2ma - 16ma) applies to GPIO output (source), not input (sink).  Second, in calculating the resistance values, I used 3.3v as the output voltage but should have used a lower voltage as 3.3v is the max safe voltage.  A HIGH signal will register with voltage as low as 1.3v, so the output voltage can probably be in the ballpark of 2v and reliably register as HIGH while remaining safely below the 3.3v max.  (contd)

Comment: Third, as Joan correctly pointed out, I should not have sized to 8ma for an input signal.  The minimum current needed to register an input is not documented anywhere I could find, but is in the microamp range (not milliamps).  When I get a chance, I will perform a test to try and measure the minimum current required for a signal.  This value will set the floor when sizing the resistors for the voltage divider.

Comment: We can make inferences from the internal pull up/down resistors on the GPIO which can be optionally enabled. The Pull-Up is 50k-65k ohms and the Pull-Down is 50k- 60k. Using the lowest signal voltage (1.3v) with the highest resistance pull resistor (65k) gives us the scenario for the lowest current draw by the GPIO input, which is 20 ua (microamps, not milliamps!). Using the highest safe voltage of 3.3v and the lowest pull resistance of 50k, the current draw works out to 66 ua. So any added components that add resistance to the input signal must allow 66 ua flow at the minimum.